# Can someone point out why my CSV generator.rb file fails?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have two CSV files.

One file is called complete_failed_list.csv and the contents look like this:

```
id, username, email, status, details
```

I want to create a new csv file called failed_id_list.csv from complete_failed_list.csv but only keep the ids.

Here is what I have.

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open('failed_id_list.csv', 'a+') do |csv_id|
   CSV.open('complete_failed_list.csv', 'r', {headers: false}) do |failed_csv_list|
      csv_id << [failed_csv_list][0]
   end
end
```

This set up gives me an error:

```
failed_email_id_generator.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]' for #<CSV:0x007ff2328d5140> (NoMethodError)
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong. I only want the first column from `failed_csv_list` which should be the `id` and then append it to the failed_id_list.csv. Why is this not working?

For my second attempt I changed the code to:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open('failed_id_list.csv', 'a+', {headers: false}) do |csv_id|
  CSV.foreach('complete_failed_list.csv', {headers: false}) do |failed_csv_list|
     csv_id << failed_csv_list[0]
  end
end
```

which produces a new error:

```
`<<': undefined method `map' for "id":String (NoMethodError)
```

When what I want is only a single column of ids without the header:

```
132
24
312
43
52
```

With the new attempt:

- I've specified the file to be created `failed_id_list.csv`.
- I've set the creation of `failed_id_list.csv` to have no headers like I want.
- I then read every line of the document that has the data `complete_failed_list.csv` and grab the first column and append it to the new document `csv_id << failed_csv_list[0]`.

I placed a `puts "#{failed_csv_list[0]}"` and I can see the ids being printed out so why am I getting this error. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block parameter which you get from `CSV#open` is not a single row, but the CSV object. So, you need to either use `CSV#foreach` instead of second `CSV#open`, or `CSV#each` within the existing block.

Edit:

`CSV#<<` method requires an array as an argument, and you are passing a scalar `failed_csv_list[0]`. If you want just a single column in your resulting CSV, just enclose it in brackets: `[failed_csv_list[0]]`.

Also, I think you should put some more effort in variable naming. It will be clearer to you what you are doing and which kind of objects are you working with. In your case:

```
CSV.open('failed_id_list.csv', 'a+', {headers: false}) do |output_csv|
  CSV.foreach('complete_failed_list.csv', {headers: false}) do |input_row|
     output_csv << [input_row[0]]
  end
end
```

Comment: Mladen thank you for the comment. You're answer has gotten me further ahead but could you please take a look at my second attempt. I would really appreciate it.